# Java : Parse array to positive and negative array

Tags: java, arrays

Below is what i done, and it is working properly, but I want to make no fixed numbers of negative and positive articles , so code can work on any array:

```
    int[] array = {15, 22, 71, -27, 33, -44, 0, 334, -82};
    int[] negative = new int[3];
    int[] positive = new int[6];
    int n = 0;
    int p = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]<0){
            negative[n] = array[i];
            n++;
        }else{
            positive[p] = array[i];
            p++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Negative array : " + Arrays.toString(negative));
    System.out.println("Positive array : " + Arrays.toString(positive));
```

Any advise ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow two different ways:

- Count negative and positive at first step, generate the arrays for negative and positives and fill them
- Create `List` for positive and negatives, fill them and convert them to arrays

If it is not necessary to have arrays of positives and negatives you can also split the original array in two lists (instead of two arrays).

---

**First possibility**

```
int numPositives = 0;
int numNegatives = 0;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if (array[i] >= 0) {
        numPositives++;
    } else {
        numNegatives++;
    }
}

int[] negative = new int[numNegatives];
int[] positive = new int[numPositives];
int n = 0;
int p = 0;

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i]<0){
        negative[n] = array[i];
        n++;
    }else{
        positive[p] = array[i];
        p++;
    }
}
```

---

**Second possibility**

```
List<Integer> positivesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> negativesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] >= 0) {
        positivesList.add(array[i]);
    } else {
        negativesList.add(array[i]);
    }
} 
int[] positive = positivesList.toArray(new int[positivesList.size()]);
int[] negative = negativesList.toArray(new int[negativesList.size()]);
```

Comment: I would like to have two arrays, not list. How to generate the array for negative and positives ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `List`, it has no fixed size:

```
int[] array = {15, 22, 71, -27, 33, -44, 0, 334, -82};
List<Integer> negative = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> positive = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i]<0){
        negative.add(array[i]); // Add negative number
    }else{
        positive.add(array[i]); // Add positive number 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has introduced streams which include lambda predicate filtering:

```
int[] pos = Arrays.stream(array).filter((int i) -> i >= 0).toArray();
int[] neg = Arrays.stream(array).filter((int i) -> i < 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @davide both approach can be used

1) Count negative and positive at first step, generate the arrays for negative and positives and fill them.

```
    int numPositives = 0;// davide example
int numNegatives = 0;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if (array[i] >= 0) {
        numPositives++;
    } else {
        numNegatives++;
    }
}

int[] negative = new int[numNegatives];
int[] positive = new int[numPositives];
int n = 0;
int p = 0;

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i]<0){
        negative[n] = array[i];
        n++;
    }else{
        positive[p] = array[i];
        p++;
    }
}
```

2) Create List for positive and negatives, fill them and convert them to arrays

```
int[] array = {15, 22, 71, -27, 33, -44, 0, 334, -82};
List<Integer> negativeList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> positiveList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i]<0){
        negativeList.add(array[i]); // Add negative number
    }else{
        positiveList.add(array[i]); // Add positive number 
    }
}
```

**//SINCE JAVA 8**

```
int negativeArray[] = negativeList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
int positiveArray[] = negativeList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here´s a little solution that doesn´t involve lists aswell as it doesn´t precompute the amount of negative values. It´s rather using the native solution to copy the values that have yet been found. I also changed it so that both, negative and positive, values are stored in a single 2d array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {15, 22, 71, -27, 33, -44, 0, 334, -82};
    int[][] vals = new int[2][0];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]<0){
            int[] buffer = new int[vals[0].length+1]; // create array with one more value
            System.arraycopy(vals[0], 0, buffer, 0, vals[0].length); // Copy old values
            buffer[buffer.length-1] = array[i]; // assign new value
            vals[0] = buffer; // assign old and new values
        } else {
            int[] buffer = new int[vals[1].length+1]; // create array with one more value
            System.arraycopy(vals[1], 0, buffer, 0, vals[1].length); // Copy old values
            buffer[buffer.length-1] = array[i]; // assign new value
            vals[1] = buffer; // assign old and new values
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Negative array : " + Arrays.toString(vals[0]));
    System.out.println("Positive array : " + Arrays.toString(vals[1]));
}
```