# How to output only numbers that are not 0, how to disable zero output?

Tags: java

I need to output only positive and negative numbers from the listed Array. Also 0 can't be output. I need a code that will pass the i over *when its 0 element. Any suggestions?

```
 class StackHelp {
int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

int[] neg = new int[array.length];

int[] poz = new int[array.length];


 for (int i=0;  i<array.length; i++ ) {

{

       if  (array[i] <= 0)

       {   if (array[i] == 0)

        array[i]++; {

       }

  neg[i] = array[i];

} else {

  poz[i] = array[i];

}

}}
```

Comment: change `array[i]++;` to `continue`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java : Parse array to positive and negative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635925/java-parse-array-to-positive-and-negative-array)

Comment: Please note that your using the loops integer `i` as index. The blank in the array results to 0

Comment: Note that your indentation is really messy. Please format your code properly, so other people can read your question more easily.

Comment: Where specifically are you having trouble?  See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take care of extra 0's being added in the array, which is not done in above answers.

```
class ExcludeZero
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int array[]={-5,-4,-3,1,2,3,4,0,-1,-2,0,5,6,7,8,-9,-8,-7,-6};
        int rawPositiveArray[]=new int[array.length];
        int rawNegativeArray[]=new int[array.length];
        int insertPositivePosition=0;
        int insertNegativePosition=0;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if(array[i]>0){
                rawPositiveArray[insertPositivePosition]=array[i];
                insertPositivePosition++;
            }else if(array[i]<0){
                rawNegativeArray[insertNegativePosition]=array[i];
                insertNegativePosition++;
            }
        }
        rawPositiveArray=trimArray(rawPositiveArray);
        rawNegativeArray=trimArray(rawNegativeArray);
    }

    private static int[] trimArray(int array[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int targetIndex = 0;
        for( int sourceIndex = 0;  sourceIndex < array.length;  sourceIndex++ )
        {
            if( array[sourceIndex] != 0 )
                array[targetIndex++] = array[sourceIndex];
        }
        int[] newArray = new int[targetIndex];
        System.arraycopy( array, 0, newArray, 0, targetIndex );
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

You can check the values of `rawPositiveArray` and `rawNegativeArray` to check the values of positive and negative arrays.

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! Now start paying more attention in your computer science class!

Here is exactly what is happening: the "continue" directive tells the for loop to drop everything that's happening and just go to the next integer.

```
class StackHelp {
     int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

     int[] neg = new int[array.length];

     int[] poz = new int[array.length];


     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

         {
             if (array[i] == 0)

                continue;

             }

             if (array[i] <= 0)

             {
                 neg[i] = array[i];

             } else {

                 poz[i] = array[i];

             }

         }
     }
```

Another thing I might suggest is adding to the next index of your arrays. Keep track of them like so:

```
class StackHelp {
     int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};


     int[] neg = new int[array.length];

     int[] poz = new int[array.length];


     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

         {
             if (array[i] == 0)

                continue;

             }

             if (array[i] <= 0)

             {
                 neg[neg.indexOf(0)] = array[i];

             } else {

                 poz[pos.indexOf(0)] = array[i];

             }

         }
     }
```

Comment: Yes i am a beginner but i knew that continue loop, still it adds up zeroes on array. This the output of the following program, same as my were on the beginning http://prntscr.com/pvtrzu . The array listed can only be positive and negative numbers, so if i==0 then don't show, your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a counter for array of negative and positive for reference counting. Also using the for loops integer `i` as index for inserting the value result to the blank index to 0 (where 0 is the default value of the integer)

You code will look something like this

```
        int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
        int[] neg = new int[array.length];
        int negcount = 0;
        int[] poz = new int[array.length];
        int pozcount = 0;

        for(int i=0;  i<array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] < 0){
                neg[negcount] = array[i];
                negcount++;
            }else if(array[i] > 0){
                poz[pozcount] = array[i];
                pozcount++;
            }
        }
        // Print value
        System.out.println("NEGATIVE");
        for(int i=0; i<negcount; i++){
            System.out.println(neg[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("POSITIVE");
        for(int i=0; i<pozcount; i++){
            System.out.println(poz[i]);
        }
```

Comment: My friend your code is very good, only problem is i need the postive and negative numbers listed as arrays. This is your output = http://prntscr.com/pvtuky, i need them as arrays listed.

Comment: @deleter They are in array, I just print it individually, please read more about array before saying they are not array

Comment: And I can't believe that my answer was not check as accepted even it solve your problem in not printing the 0?

Comment: I need the output in arrays, not as integer

Comment: Then tell me what do you mean by output as array?
you like a `[12,12,12]` in string?
and as you know I just print it individually, but they are in the ARRAY.
AND DO YOU REALLY KNOW WHAT ARE ARRAYS?